# Clean up Android Studio's maven

Tags: maven

My `C:\Users\me\.AndroidStudioBeta\system\Maven` folder is almost 5 gigabytes I cannot afford.

Is there any safe way of cleaning this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to delete the stuff in it at exactly that level. The indexes will be recreated the next time the IDE is open.